# Broken encoding after postback

Tags: c#, asp.net, unicode, encoding, character-encoding

I have a query string with a parameter value that contains the norwegian character `å` encoded as `%e5`. The page contains a form with an action attribute which is automatically filled by ASP.Net. When the URL is output into said attribute it is printed with a full two byte encoding: `%u00e5`.

When posting back this seems to be ok when debugging the code behind. However the page actually does a redirect to itself (for some other reason) and the redirect location header looks like this:  `Location: /myFolder/MyPage.aspx?Param1=%C3%A5`

So the `%e5` has been translated to `%C3%A5` which breaks the output somehow.

In HTML text the broken characters look like `&#195;&#165;` after having been output via HttpUtility.HtmlEncode.

The entire web application is ISO8859-1 encoded.

PS. When removing the u00 from the output `%u00e5` in the action attribute before posting the form, everything is output nicely. But the error seems to be the translation from `%e5` to `%C3%A5`. (And of course the self redirect, but that's another matter.)

Any pointers?

Comment: It's not an error, `%C3%A5` is simply the URL-encoded UTF-8 version of å. The error is in the conversion to HTML: every encoded UTF-8 sequence in the URL must be converted back to an Unicode code point and then HTML-encoded.

Comment: Actually it seems that the URL encoding is correct when it is `%e5` for `å` according to http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp . It seems that the problem is that the redirect IIS outputs the `location` header with utf-8 encoding, i.e. `%e5` is translated into `%c3%a5`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I ended up with was encoding the redirect URL manually.

```
public void ReloadPage()
{
    UrlBuilder url = new UrlBuilder(Context, Request.Path);
    foreach (string queryParam in Request.QueryString.AllKeys)
    {
        string queryParamValue = Request.QueryString[queryParam];
        url.AddQueryItem(queryParam, queryParamValue);
    }
    Response.Redirect( url.ToString(), true);
}
```

The url.AddQueryItem basically does HttpContext.Server.UrlDecode(queryParamValue) and the url.ToString builds the query string and for each query item does HttpContext.Server.UrlEncode( queryParamValue).

The UrlBuilder is a class already present in our library, so once I found the problem and realized that C#/.Net didn't provide tools for this, coding the fix was quick :)